# Nested array loop in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How would I loop a JSON object like the one below with v-for? 
I want to loop all ID's/Numbers, and all items in inside each number, and display it all in a list...
I know I can loop all system_events easily using `v-for="item in system_events"`
But how do I loop all different ID's/Numbers, and all items inside ?

My JSON looks like:

```
{
    "system_events": {
        "1013": [{
                "id": 25899,
                "timestamp": "2017-08-15T21:26:42Z",
                "type": "alarm",
                "code": 190,
                "title": "",
                "description": "",
                "appeared": "2017-08-15T21:26:40Z",
                "disappeared": null,
                "acknowlegded": null,
                "solved": null,
                "system_name": "Randers pr 44b sidste station"
            }, {
                "id": 26157,
                "timestamp": "2017-08-15T21:32:17Z",
                "type": "alarm",
                "code": 190,
                "title": "",
                "description": "",
                "appeared": "2017-08-15T21:32:06Z",
                "disappeared": null,
                "acknowlegded": null,
                "solved": null,
                "system_name": "Randers pr 44b sidste station"
            }
        ],
        "1015": [{
                "id": 23777,
                "timestamp": "2017-08-15T20:38:08Z",
                "type": "alarm",
                "code": 191,
                "title": "",
                "description": "",
                "appeared": "2017-08-15T20:38:00Z",
                "disappeared": null,
                "acknowlegded": null,
                "solved": null,
                "system_name": "Favrskov Svenstrup gyvelvej"
            }, {
                "id": 23779,
                "timestamp": "2017-08-15T20:38:08Z",
                "type": "alarm",
                "code": 190,
                "title": "",
                "description": "",
                "appeared": "2017-08-15T20:37:58Z",
                "disappeared": null,
                "acknowlegded": null,
                "solved": null,
                "system_name": "Favrskov Svenstrup gyvelvej"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: just add another `v-for="subitem in item"` element inside the first `v-for` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Bert's answer, I'll say you can use a `template` tag in order not to render the main frame. This is useful for instance if you want a clean HTML `ul>li` only for subitems.

```js
const vue = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    system_events: {"1013":[{"id":25899},{"id":26157}],"1015":[{"id":23777},{"id":23779}]}
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <template v-for="item in system_events">
      <li v-for="event in item">{{ event.id }}</li>
    </template>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use a `template` in this case, not a `slot`

Comment: Edited, but may I know the reason why? [I saw this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Template-v-for), but maybe you have more accurate

Comment: `<slot>` is used to interweave content. `<template>` is simply logic that you want (in this case, an outer `for` loop) without any accompanying DOM node.

Comment: Like Terry said, use `templates` for content composition within a component, and `slots` for content distribution between components. Anything in an unnamed `slot` tag will be replaced by the contents of a component's tag. See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/q70aw981/

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use a computed property to simplify your data structure:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    system_events: {"1013":[{"id":25899},{"id":26157}],"1015":[{"id":23777},{"id":23779}]}    
  },
  computed: {
    allEvents: function() {
      return Object.values(this.system_events)
        .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="event in allEvents">{{event.id}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This allows you to use a simple loop in the template, which makes the structure of your markup clearer.

If you're working with large data sets, and/or the data are mutated frequently, you might want to test both these approaches for performance. I have no idea which one would be better.

Comment: I'd rather use this than my solution nowadays! Especially because you can use [`array.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/flat). It [can be used](https://caniuse.com/#feat=array-flat) since chrome 69 or with babel. `return Object.values(this.system_events).flat()`

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @UlysseBN. And good point about `array.flat`.